# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<List<Brew>> above this BrewList Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

it has a simple solution but i =cant find it . I have tried some solutions on github and stack overflow but it didnt work.
lets take a look at my code :

here is my brewlist.dart :

```
class BrewList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final brew = Provider.of<List<Brew>>(context);

    brew.forEach((brew) {
      print(brew.name);
      print(brew.strength);
      print(brew.sugars);
    });

    return Container();
  }
}
```

its above widget is here in the home.dart file

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AuthService _authService = AuthService();
    return StreamProvider<List<Brew>?>.value(
      initialData: null,
      value: DataBase('fjsbfjjhsbdfgvbdkbvkj').brews,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[50],
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.brown[400],
          elevation: 12,
          title: Text('Brew Crew'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton.icon(
              onPressed: () async {
                await _authService.signOut();
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.person,
                color: Colors.brown[800],
              ),
              label: Text(
                'log out',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.brown[800]),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: BrewList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

brewlist is the body of my scaffold as you can see we have the StreamProvider wrapped around the scaffold to have the data passing through its childs {which brewlist is one of them ..

here is my main.dart file :

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ToggleView>(create: (_) => ToggleView()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<LoadingIndicator>(
            create: (_) => LoadingIndicator()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

enter code here
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<Userr?>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      initialData: Userr(useruid: 'No user found'),
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i really dont understand this long error :

The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building BrewList(dirty):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<List> above this BrewList Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that BrewList is under your MultiProvider/Provider<List>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Provider(
  create: (_) => Example(),
  // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
  // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
  child: Text(context.watch()),
  ),
  }

consider using `builder` like so:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }
```

If none of these solutions work, consider asking for help on StackOverflow:

i dont why I get this error if you can provide solution please help
i really appreciate your help inadvacne.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple, my friend.

Just go to **brew_list.dart** file and add the following line

```
final brews = Provider.of<List<Brew?>?>(context) ?? [];
```

That's it, you are good to go :)